# Text does not appear on screen even if mouse position is on the necessary coordinates

Tags: processing

I want to have text printed out on the condition that the mouse positions hover over a certain coordinate range for both *x* and *y* coordinates. However, the text can not print even if I state in the code that the text should be printed if its on a certain coordinate range. Can anyone offer me some advice towards what I should be doing? Any help can be appreciated.

**The code to print the text is after the "// Gamma" comment**

```
PImage[] imgs;
String[] greekAlphabet = {"Gamma", "Zeta", "Eta", "Kappa", "Lambda", "Phi", "Psi"};

void setup(){
  background(0);
  size(500, 500);
  textSize(50);
  textAlign(CENTER, CENTER);
  
  imgs = new PImage[greekAlphabet.length];
  for (int i = 0; i < imgs.length; i++){
    imgs[i] = loadImage(greekAlphabet[i]+".png");
  }
  
  text("Press Any Key", width/2, height/2);
}

void draw(){
  if (keyPressed){
    background(0);
    text("Choose any clan", width/2, height/2 - 180);
    for (int i = 0; i < imgs.length; i++){
      if (i >= 0 && i <= 3){
        image(imgs[i], (((i)%5 * 120)), 120, 150, 150);        
      }
      else if (i >=4 && i <= 6){
        image(imgs[i], (55+((i)%4 * 120)), 310, 150, 150);        
      }
    }
    
    // Gamma
    if (overImage(25, 120, 140, 250)){
      text("Gamma", width/2, height/2);
    }
    
  }
  println(mouseX + " " + mouseY);
}

boolean overImage(int x1, int x2, int y1, int y2){
  if ((mouseX >= x1 && mouseX <= x2) && (mouseY >= y1 && mouseY <= y2)){
    return true;
  }
  else{
    return false;
  } 
}
```

Comment: You're printing the text within the `if (keypressed)` conditional. That means the text will only print if a key is down while the mouse is over that area. Is that what you want? Otherwise I don't see any obvious problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As noted above the if(keyPressed) needs to be removed.  The following works on my system.  I changed the images to some that I had for testing purposes; you'll need to change them back for your setup.  I also added an extra display function to simplify things a little.  There is likely more optimization that could be done.  Make sure that the _imgW and _imgH values are correct for your images.

```
PImage[] imgs;
String[] greekAlphabet = {"Gamma", "Omega", "Delta", "Alpha", "Sigma", "Phi", "Psi"};
final int _imgW = 150;
final int _imgH = 150;

void displayImages() {
  text("Choose any clan", width/2, height/2 - 180);
  for (int i = 0; i < imgs.length; i++) {
    if (i >= 0 && i <= 3) {
      image(imgs[i], (((i)%5 * 120)), 120, _imgW, _imgH);
    } else if (i >=4 && i <= 6) {
      image(imgs[i], (55+((i)%4 * 120)), 310, _imgW, _imgH);
    }
  }
}

void setup() {
  background(0);
  size(600, 500);
  textSize(30);
  textAlign(CENTER, CENTER);
  imgs = new PImage[greekAlphabet.length];
  for (int i = 0; i < imgs.length; i++) {
    imgs[i] = loadImage(greekAlphabet[i]+".png");
  }
}

void draw() {
  background(0);
  displayImages();
  if (overImage(0, 120)) {
    text("Gamma", 120, 20);
  }
  if (overImage(120, 120)) {
    text("Omega", 120, 20);
  }
  if (overImage(240, 120)) {
    text("Delta", 120, 20);
  }
  if (overImage(360, 120)) {
    text("Alpha", 120, 20);
  }
  if (overImage(55, 310)) {
    text("Sigma", 120, 20);
  }
  if (overImage(175, 310)) {
    text("Phi", 120, 20);
  }
  if (overImage(245, 310)) {
    text("Psi", 120, 20);  
  }
   println("x = ", mouseX + " : " + "y =", mouseY);
}

boolean overImage(int x, int y) {
  if (mouseX >= x && mouseX <= x+_imgW && mouseY >= y && mouseY <= y+_imgH) {
    return true;
  } else {
    return false;
  }
}
```